# How to apply & operator to a boolean matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix such as

```
matrix(sample(c(T,F),12,replace=T),3,4 )
```

and the result is

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

i am looking for the shortest way to apply `AND (&)` operator into the all all matrix. So, that if there is a `FALSE` the output should be ***false*** as well.

i know, how loops work, but i am looking for a shorter solution

Comment: Can you show expected output? Also don't forget to set a seed for reproducibility.

Comment: What do you want to AND the matrix with? Another matrix?  A single TRUE/FALSE value? What have you tried?

Comment: the expected output is single `True` or `False`. i dont know, how to use `setseed`

Comment: are you looking for `all(M)` ?

Comment: i wish to AND all the enteries together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any matrix `m`:

```
> m
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`c(m)` will flatten that matrix into a vector:

```
> c(m)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

So for AND of all the elements to be TRUE, its necessary for all elements to be TRUE. Hence:

```
> all(c(m))
[1] FALSE
```

In this case you can omit the `c` and do it directly:

```
> all(m)
[1] FALSE
```

In a more general case, you can apply a function to pairs of elements of a vector with `Reduce`, for example:

```
> Reduce("&", c(m))
[1] FALSE
```

which returns `m[1,1] & m[1,2] & m[1,3] ... & m[3,4]` - or possibly in the other order. But `all` is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```r
m <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),12,replace=T),3,4 )
!sum(!m)
```

Indeed go with `all(m)`, it is the fastest approach.

```r
library(microbenchmark)

m <- matrix(sample(c(T, F), 12, replace = T), 3, 4)
v1 <- c(rep(TRUE, 100000), FALSE)
v2 <- c(rep(FALSE, 100000), TRUE)
microbenchmark(all(m),
!sum(!m),
Reduce("&", c(m))
)
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>               expr   min      lq     mean  median      uq   max neval
#>             all(m)   180   196.5   321.95   307.0   390.0  2009   100
#>           !sum(!m)   480   568.0   872.71   743.5   961.5  7310   100
#>  Reduce("&", c(m)) 11811 12552.0 13773.78 12785.5 13324.5 60542   100
microbenchmark(all(v1),
               !sum(!v1),
               Reduce("&", c(v1))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq
#>             all(v1)   182.243   182.7665   194.1427   191.5655   197.4315
#>           !sum(!v1)   222.820   229.6120   252.6130   241.8500   270.7170
#>  Reduce("&", c(v1)) 49630.995 50749.8915 52422.5430 52030.7920 53034.9625
#>        max neval
#>    250.658   100
#>    365.297   100
#>  84738.200   100
microbenchmark(all(v2),
               !sum(!v2),
               Reduce("&", c(v2))
)
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>                expr      min         lq        mean     median       uq
#>             all(v2)      180      275.0     1416.92      396.0     3213
#>           !sum(!v2)   223276   227139.5   253327.79   259543.5   273641
#>  Reduce("&", c(v2)) 47403495 50349576.5 51972709.38 51785602.5 52767908
#>       max neval
#>      8929   100
#>    342353   100
#>  85463431   100
```

Comment: `all(m)` is even shorter indeed :)

Comment: Note also that `all` will stop the test when it finds the first FALSE value and return FALSE. Try benchmarking a vector of all FALSE or all TRUE or all TRUE with first or last element FALSE...